# How to get the entire polyline to be visible on a google map

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-maps

I have a polyline that I get from a [directions request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start) and I want it to show a google map with all the points visible but I do not know how to get the camera to show all the points. 
I add the polyline like this:

```
fun MapFragment.addPolyline(line: String) {
    val decodedPath: List<LatLng> = PolyUtil.decode(line)
    getMap()?.addPolyline(PolylineOptions().addAll(decodedPath))
}
```

Then I center the camera on one of the points like this:

```
fun MapFragment.setCamera(latLng: LatLng) {
    getMap()?.moveCamera(
        CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            latLng, 20f
        )
    )
}
```

However this only shows part of the polyline. I need the zoom to change so as the map covers the entire polyline. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the latlngbound .You can use this methods to draw polyline of whole points.

```
fun drawPolyline(listlatlng: ArrayList<LatLng>) {
var latlngHistory: ArrayList<LatLng> = ArrayList()
        val bc = LatLngBounds.Builder()
        for (item in listlatlng) {
            latlngHistory.add(item)
            bc.include(item)
        }
        mMap?.clear()
        var path: Polyline = mMap!!.addPolyline(
            PolylineOptions().addAll(latlngHistory)
        )
        path.width = 10F
        path.color = Color.parseColor("#A3258F")

        if (latlngHistory != null && latlngHistory.size != 0) {
            if (latlngHistory.size < 2) {
                bc.include(latlngHistory.get(0))
                bc.include(latlngHistory.get(latlngHistory.size - 1))
            }
            //cardll is a layout refernce on which map is displaying
            val width = cardll?.width
            val height = cardll?.height
            if (width != null && height != null) {
                mMap!!.moveCamera(
                    CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(
                        bc.build(),
                        width!!,
                        height!!,
                        60
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
```